# shell script execution sequence

Tags: debugging, shell

I'm debugging a shell script
so I add set -x at the beginning
a code snippet are as below

```
tcpdump -i $interface host $ip_addr and 'port 80' -w flash/flash.pcap &
sudo -u esolve firefox /tor_capture/flash.html &
sleep $capture_time
```

but I noticed that the execution sequence is as below

```
++ sleep 5
++ sudo -u esolve firefox /tor_capture/flash.html
++ tcpdump -i eth0 host 138.96.192.56 and 'port 80' -w flash/flash.pcap
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
```

so the execution sequence is reversed compared to the command sequence in the script
what is wrong with this and how to deal with it?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since those lines are being backgrounded, I think the output from `set -x` comes from the subshell that is spawned to run the program, and the main shell gets to the `sleep` command before the subshells have proceeded to the point that they generate the output. That would explain why the `sleep` command shows up first. With regards to the other two, I would think you might occasionally get them in the other order, as well, since there's no synchronization between the two - depending on how many CPUs you have, how busy the system is, etc., the timing between the subshells is pseudo-non-deterministic...

Comment: so in a shell script how can I make these three command run in the order as i specified?

Comment: They are being started in the order that you specify. They just don't get to the point where they log that fact in that same order. That's inherent in running things in the background/concurrently... If you need to guarantee that, for example, `tcpdump` is completely initialized before you start `firefox`, put some `sleep 5` lines in between or something...

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the first 2 lines to run as background processes?

If not, remove the `&` at the end and try again.

Comment: I need them to run as background processes, coz I need to capture packets for some time  and then kill these tcpdump and firefox